# What is the energy output of Solar thermal collector?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, power, sun, thermoelectricity

I have a solar thermal collector. Its LCD screen shows an output of about 5KWH at the end of the day. How to interpret this number? Is this electrical KW (kilo watt)?  If yes, isn't too low for a 1.5x2m (well, I am not sure about its size since it is on the roof) solar panel collector? If no, how do I convert it to electrical equivalent?

I would like to compare its energy with the one provided by an electrical heater because this I understand better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A kWh is a kilo-Watt-hour: that is, if you collected 5 kWh over the course of a day, and you had the sun shining for 10 hours, then you would on average have generated 500 W continuously (500 W times 10 hours = 5000 Watt - hours = 5 kWh).

If you were trying to convert sunlight to electrical power, this would be reasonable. If the solar panel is pointing directly at the sun, it can receive about 1 kW of power per unit area. PV efficiency is around 15% (these are all ballpark numbers: a lot depends on technology, where you are, how much sunlight you get, how well the panel is aimed at the sun, whether it is tracking, ...). So with a 3 m$^2$ panel, 15% efficiency would give you about 450 W.

But since you are trying to collect HEAT, other factors come into it: construction of the collector, temperature of the inlet (and outlet) water, external temperature all play a role. The efficiency is usually higher than for PV systems - but depending on other factors (in particular how well your system is aimed at the sun) the number you quote isn't too far off. And since you don't even know how big your panel is, you probably shouldn't be too concerned.

If you get actual information about the design, where you are located geographically, how the collector is pointed at the sun, what time of year you did the measurement, etc, it would be possible to give a better answer. With the limited data you gave, I think "yeah, about right" is all you can hope for.

Comment: Thanks. I live in north Germany. Extremely dark/cloudy out here. Yesterday it was sunny all day and the panel registered 10KWH! The constructor of the house left no manual for the panel (or for any other device) so I don't know the exact size of the panel. Maybe I can get some measurement without going on the roof :)

Comment: According to this image https://goo.gl/images/A2BTLZ you can expect solar irradiation of about 900 kWh per year per square meter where you live - obviously biased towards summer.